# Explorar directorio del servidor desde la aplicacion web para obtener la ruta de directorio

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, mvc

Estoy trabajando en una página web intranet, esta no tiene comunicación con internet, así que problemas de seguridad no debería haber.
El punto es que requiero que cuando el usuario este en un formulario al ingresar a una opción en la que le va pedir la ruta para guardar archivos la tiene que seleccionar pero está es en el servidor NO en la maquina del usuario, una vez ahi solo tiene que seleccionar el directorio y el path o ruta deberá aparecer en el input habilitado para ello.
El proyecto es .net MVC3 trate con JqueryFileTree pero solo me da hasta la ruta de la carpeta del proyecto.

```
[HttpPost]
    //notice the added additional params to the expected request variables
    //these appear to match the names of the jQuery options
    public virtual JsonResult GetFiles(string dir, bool multiSelect,
        bool onlyFolders, bool onlyFiles)
    {


        const string baseDir = @"../";

        dir = Server.UrlDecode(dir);

        string realDir = Server.MapPath(baseDir + dir);

        //validate to not go above basedir
        if (!realDir.StartsWith(Server.MapPath(baseDir)))
        {
            realDir = Server.MapPath(baseDir);
            dir = "/";
        }

        List<todosModelosBaseDatos.FileTreeViewModel> files = new List<todosModelosBaseDatos.FileTreeViewModel>();

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(realDir);

        foreach (DirectoryInfo dc in di.GetDirectories())
        {
            files.Add(new todosModelosBaseDatos.FileTreeViewModel() { Name = dc.Name, Path = String.Format("{0}{1}\\", dir, dc.Name), IsDirectory = true });
        }

        foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
        {
            files.Add(new todosModelosBaseDatos.FileTreeViewModel() { Name = fi.Name, Ext = fi.Extension.Substring(1).ToLower(), Path = dir + fi.Name, IsDirectory = false });
        }
        //lets filter some results using the properties of 
        //the `FileTreeViewModel()` class
        //I have no idea how you are wanting to use multiSelect, so 
        //it has been left out of this example.
        if (onlyFolders)
        {
            files = files.Where(x => x.IsDirectory).ToList();
        }
        if (onlyFiles)
        {
            files = files.Where(x => !x.IsDirectory).ToList();
        }
        return Json(new { data = files});

    }
```

Este ejercicio solo me da C:\users\desktop\carpetaProyecto

Si me muestra las carpetas contenidas en el proyecto pero eso no es lo que requiero, requiero un explorador más a fondo que pudiera navegar por el servidor o por lo menos en carpetas definidas para ello.
¿Alguien tiene alguna idea o libreria?

Comment: No se si mostrarle la ruta del servidor sea buena idea, por mas que sea un proyecto de intranet.. y si mañana cambias las cosas de carpetas? y si mañana renombras todas las carpetas?? yo creo que lo mas facil es armar unas "rutas virtuales" y vos despues mapearlas a donde quieras fisicamente...

Comment: Es que asi son los requerimientos levantados, pero explicame eso de las rutas virtuales, como es eso?

Comment: Le inventas un filesystem, donde va guardando cosas, pero las rutas reales se las escondes y vos guardas en las rutas reales, de forma tal que si esas rutas reales mañana cambian (porque se lleno un disco por ejemplo) es transparente para el usuario...

Comment: oye eso es excelente. Muchas gracias

Comment: Obviamente eso no sirve como respuesta. Tenes un par de opciones, o escribir una autorespuesta cuando resuelvas la aplicacion, con el codigo que usaste. o borrar la pregunta, ya que no tiene mucho sentido. Como respuesta, es mas una sugerencia que te hace mas facil la vida, que una respuesta real...